# android show widget programmatically

Tags: android, widget

I craeted application whic has both GUI part and Widget. How can I show/hide Widget from GUI part?

Comment: By "widget" do you mean "widget" (subclass of `android.view.View`) or "app widget" (thing that goes on the home screen)?

Comment: AppWidget, which locates on Home screen

Answer (score 1):

[this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html) should be useful.If you return RESULT_CANCELED, the host will cancel the add and not display this AppWidget, and you will receive a ACTION_APPWIDGET_DELETED broadcast.

Comment: As I've understood AppWidgetManager uses as preferences for the widget. I mean that I have standalone applciation which support its own widget. And I need show/hide MyApplication's widget on the HOME